# Lightspeed E-commerce - webhooks (CART)

Tags: e-commerce, webhooks, lightspeed

I'm trying to make some custom integration with Lightspeed e-commerce platform and I need a way connect with add_to_cart/ update_cart action, but I cannot find ANY hook connected to this event. Is it even possible in Lightspeed? Dev documentation says absolutely nothing about add to cart/update... any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture this action by creating a webhook to quote/updated. When the shoppingcart gets updated, a request is posted to your given url with all required information. Take a look at this page: https://developers.lightspeedhq.com/ecom/endpoints/quote/

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set a webhook is posting:

https://api.yourshop.com/en/webhooks.json

```
{
  "webhook": {
    "isActive": true,
    "itemGroup": "orders",
    "itemAction": "*",
    "language": "en",
    "format": "json",
    "address": "https://yourwebhook.com/"
  }
}
```

Notice that the field `itemAction` has a `*` witch will receive the actions `created|updated|deleted`

More info here:
https://developers.lightspeedhq.com/ecom/endpoints/webhook/#post-create-a-webhook